# Get name of All Constraints from access table in java

Tags: java, ms-access-2007

How can I get all constraints like Primary Key and Foreign Key defined in MS Access database.
For MySql, we use `describe table_name`

Similarly, what is the query for MS Access for using it in java program?

Comment: how can i achieve this.

Comment: Is it Possible to implement such thing in java

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DescQueryOutput{

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
      try 
      {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
          String query = "DESC newaccount";

          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
          System.out.println("COLUMN NAME\tDATATYPE\tNULL\tKEY\tDEFAULT\tEXTRA");
  while (rs.next())
  {
      System.out.print(rs.getString(1)+"\t");
      System.out.print(rs.getString(2)+"\t");
      System.out.print(rs.getString(3)+"\t");
      System.out.print(rs.getString(4)+"\t");
      System.out.print(rs.getString(5)+"\t");
      System.out.println(rs.getString(6));
  }
      }

      catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      finally {
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes,this is the query for mysql
But i want query for MS Access.

Comment: just change the connection according to ms access

Comment: but "desc table_name" query is not supported in MS Access